# How to force kaminari show the first link given the page is on the first page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

How to force kaminari show the first link given the page is on the first page

My expectation is that **even** the page is alreday on the **first page**.

The pagination should also show the **previous_link**, the **`first_page_link`**.But only display the link text, disable the **link function**

[image]

Comment: so, you are trying to show the "previous" and "first page" link buttons but disable them if the page is the first page, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the links "first_page" and "previous_page" (or the "last_page" and "next_page") always even if is the first page, you should run this command in your terminal, you must be located at the same directory as the project

```
rails g kaminari:views default
```

This will generate the files for the kaminari views, then you should go to the "_paginator.html.erb" and remove the "unless"

### views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb

```
<%= paginator.render do %>
  <nav class="pagination">
    <%= first_page_tag unless current_page.first? %>
    <%= prev_page_tag unless current_page.first? %>
    <% each_page do |page| %>
      <% if page.left_outer? || page.right_outer? || page.inside_window? %>
        <%= page_tag page %>
      <% elsif !page.was_truncated? %>
        <%= gap_tag %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= next_page_tag unless current_page.last? %>
    <%= last_page_tag unless current_page.last? %>
  </nav>
<% end %>
```

So you will need to change that file and leave it like this

### views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb

```
<%= paginator.render do %>
  <nav class="pagination">
    <%= first_page_tag %>
    <%= prev_page_tag %>
    <% each_page do |page| %>
      <% if page.left_outer? || page.right_outer? || page.inside_window? %>
        <%= page_tag page %>
      <% elsif !page.was_truncated? %>
        <%= gap_tag %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= next_page_tag %>
    <%= last_page_tag %>
  </nav>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

`kaminari` sets the first page link with the following code in [kaminari/app/views/kaminari/_first_page.html.erb](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/5c5e9af3c72d910331fd7cbcebe919450f86dffc/app/views/kaminari/_first_page.html.erb)

```
<span class="first">
  <%= link_to_unless current_page.first?, t('views.pagination.first').html_safe, url, :remote => remote %>
</span>
```

The link gets added only if the current page is not the first page.

You can easily modify this code [by customizing the kaminari views](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#customizing-the-pagination-helper)

Run `rails g kaminari:views default`; it creates a local copy of all the views used by kaminari.

So you will see a `app/views/kaminari/_first_page.html.erb` file in your app with the same code as above. Change it to suit your needs.

Example, to make it show the link text for the first page when on first page, change the logic as follows:

```
<span class="first">
  <% if current_page.first? %>
    <%= t('views.pagination.first' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to t('views.pagination.first').html_safe, url, :remote => remote %>
  <% end %>
</span>
```

Same applies to the previous link; the logic in `app/views/kaminari/_prev_page.html.erb` can be changed to make it show as needed.